# Playing multiple videos on smart TV

Tags: html5-video, samsung-smart-tv

I am creating a samsung smart tv application which can play videos from a playlist. As of  now  this example is working fine on browsers but not on emulator.

HOW TO PLAY MULTIPLE VIDEOS ON SAMSUNG SMART TV USING JAVASCRIPT AND HTML5?

code:

```
<div id="playlist1" class="sv_playlist">
  <div class="video_wrap">
    <video id="video1" poster="frame1.jpg" width="640" height="360" preload="none">
      <source src="video1.mp4"/>
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="video_wrap">
    <video id="video2" poster="frame2.jpg" width="640" height="360" preload="none">
      <source src="video2.mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
  <ul class="thumbs">
    <li id="thumbnail_v1">
      <a href="v1.mp4">
        <img alt="Thumbnail 1" src="thumbnail1.jpg" width="144" height="81" />
        <span class="play"/>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="thumbnail_v2">
      <a href="v2.mp4">
        <img alt="Thumbnail 2" src="thumbnail2.jpg" width="144" height="81" />
        <span class="play"/>
      </a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Caps lock will not help... show some code too

Comment: @sachleen have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Samsung support only 1 video on page. You cant play more than 1 video. If you want make thumnails, try animated gifs.